# how to bundle cefpython1 to py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm getting

**ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading cefpython1\cefpython_py27.pyd**

When *bundle_options* is set to 1 or 2.

I've tried to use solution suggested in [How to compile cefpython to exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668568/how-to-compile-cefpython-to-exe)
but it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that libcef.dll should not be included to python library file. 
It should be located in the same folder with .exe file and excluded from library file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your setup.py in the same location where you have the module you ar trying to covnert to executable.

After that run

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

from that location. This should solve common import problems when running py2exe to create executable.